# Solving a system of two equations in two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I teach SAT Mathematics for a test prep company and recently came across this problem.

> $$ \begin{cases}
> y=ax-9 \\
> y=x^2 - 2x
> \end{cases} $$
>   In the system of equations above, $a$ is a constant. For which of the following values of $a$ does the system of equations have exactly one real solution.
>
> A.) $-8$
>   B.) $-3$
>   C.) $4$
>   D.) $8$

The answer is C.) $4$, however, from setting the two equations equal to each other and solving for $a$, it seems as if $-8$ is also a plausible solution.

Namely, it seems the graph of of $-8x-9$ and $4x-9$ are both tangent to $x^2-2x$ at $x=-3$ and $x=3$ respectively.

I utilized elementary calculus and found the tangent line at $x=-3$ to be $y=-8x-9$ and at $x=3$ the tangent line to be $y=4x-9$.

I know these problems go through a round of reviews, I just wanted to make sure I was correct before notifying the company.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Is this supposed to be $$y=ax-9\\y=x^2-2x$$

Comment: $y=-8x-9y=x^2-2x$ has two real solutions.  $x=y=0$ and $x=6/5,y=-24/25$.  If saulspatz's guess is right, then you are correct.

Comment: Two different equations, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-(2+a)x+9=0\;\text{ has a unique solution}\;\iff \Delta=(2+a)^2-36=0\iff$$

$$a+2=\pm6\iff a=\begin{cases}&\;\;\,6-2=4\\or\\{}&-6-2=-8\end{cases}$$

Both solutions above are equally plausible without further given conditions, and thus I'd say both (a), (c) are acceptable answers. No need of calculus, btw.